# Is it possible that the interaction effect is significant while the individual effect(s) is not?

Tags: model

Consider a simple model: Y = A + B + A*B

Is it possible that coefficient for A*B is significant while that for A or B or both of them is insignificant? Either yes or no, can you tell what's the reason behind it?